# Working with autofield and unique_constraint Django

Tags: python, django

My models.py of class app:

Teacher and StudentInfo will store their respective details.

```py
from form.models import StudentInfo
from teacherform.models import Teacher

class ClassRoom(models.Model):
     standard = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     section = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     teacher = models.OneToOneField(Teacher, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class ClassRoomStudent(models.Model):
     classRoom = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     rollNumber = models.AutoField()
     student = models.OneToOneField(StudentInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to  auto increment 'rollNumber' when I add new row to my ClassRoomStudents, but if the student is from different class then rollNumber count should reset it should start again. As different students can have the same roll number if they are from different classrooms.

I am aware of [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint). But even after unique_constraint I am still not sure how my rollNumber will increment of different classrooms.
Like won't it be continuosly incrementing the rollNumber number which will obviously be unique for different or same class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `AutoField` because you can't *conditionally* increment it's value.

Instead, you can use an `IntegerField`, override the `save` method, add your conditions there and set the value of that field before saving.

Just to clarify it more, basically you should have:

```
class ClassRoomStudent(models.Model):
    classRoom = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rollNumber = models.IntegerField()
    student = models.OneToOneField(StudentInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE

    def save (self):
        if <queryset_that_verify_student_is_from_this_class_exists>:
            self.rollNumber = ClassRoomStudent.objects.filter(classRoom=self.classRoom).last().rollNumber + 1
        else:
            self.rollNumber = 1
        return super().save()
```

Comment: thanks, wouldn't the if condition be `ClassRoomStudent.objects.filter(classroom = self.classRoom)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's it!